# Servlet response is not displaying on webpage

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Hi I am new to java coding, i trying to create dynamic web page in eclipse. this is my demoServlet.java code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/demoServlet")
public class demoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public demoServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
             response.setContentType("text/html");
             PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
             out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \''>");
             out.println("<html>");
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<script language=\'JavaScript\'>");
             RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/javascript/Validate.js");
             rd.include(request, response);
             out.println("</script>");
             out.println("</head>");
             out.println("<body>"); 
             out.println("<form action=\'/myWebprj/Success.jsp onSubmit=\'return Validateusername(this.username.value)\'>");
             out.println("UserName: <input type=\'text\' name=\'username\'>");
             out.println("<input type=\'submit\' value=\'Submit\'>");
             out.println("</form>");
             out.println("</body>");
             out.println("</html>");
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

this is my JSP page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>My First jsp page in servlets</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      Its Successfully completed
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript page

```
function Validateusername(username)
{
    var returnValue=true;
    if(username=""){
        alert("Enter username is empty");
        returnValue=false;
    }  
    return returnValue;
}
```

when i am trying to enter SUBMIT button its showing me the error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /myWebprj/Success.jsp%20onSubmit=

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /myWebprj/Success.jsp%20onSubmit=

description The requested resource is not available.

Can any one help me out . whats is the error in the code...?
```

Comment: Your are missing a closing quotation mark in the end of: **\'/myWebprj/Success.jsp**

Comment: is there any particular reason for assigning return value to false in the js function. Have you tired using empty string. Just a guess

Comment: Please show us the UI code where you call the servlet.  I am convinced there is some very small mistake causing your problems.

Comment: Just use:
**<form action=\'/myWebprj/Success.jsp\' ...**
instead of:
**<form action=\'/myWebprj/Success.jsp ...**

Comment: 6 upvotes for a starter's mistake on code full of bad practices? Mind-boggling ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might it be possible that you are somehow accessing your `demoServlet` servlet using `POST` instead of `GET`?  This would explain your error message.  Please check your JavaScript console to make certain it is using `GET`.

Also, please modify your `doPost()` method to the following:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

If this resolves the error, then we have the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me! I only have removed the return keyword from the onsubmit event attribute. I also have modified the code a bit to properly assign the username to the javascript function.

```js
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/demoServlet")
public class demoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public demoServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
             response.setContentType("text/html");
             PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
             
             String username = request.getParameter("username");

             out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \''>");
             out.println("<html>");
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<script language=\'JavaScript\'>");
             RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/javascript/Validate.js");
             rd.include(request, response);
             out.println("</script>");
             out.println("</head>");
             out.println("<body>"); 
             /*
             onSubmit should call only 'Validateusername()'
             so the the 'return' keyword has been removed
             */
             out.println("<form action=\'/Test/Success.jsp\' onSubmit=\'Validateusername(" + username + ")\'>");
             out.println("UserName: <input type=\'text\' name=\'username\'>");
             out.println("<input type=\'submit\' value=\'Submit\'>");
             out.println("</form>");
             out.println("</body>");
             out.println("</html>");
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

```js
function Validateusername(username)
{
    var returnValue=true;
    if(username == undefined || username == null || username == ""){
        alert("Enter username is empty");
        returnValue=false;
    }  
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet code looks fine. The only change you need to make is in Validate.js file.
When validating username for empty you have used "=":

```
 if(username=""){ // your code }
```

Instead you use "==", it works fine.

```
 if(username==""){ // your code }
```